# Pygtk entry placeholder

Tags: python, pygtk

How to create pygtk entry with placeholder like in HTML 5 input element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code if it does what you need:

```
import gtk


class PlaceholderEntry(gtk.Entry):

    placeholder = 'Username'
    _default = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        gtk.Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.connect('focus-in-event', self._focus_in_event)
        self.connect('focus-out-event', self._focus_out_event)

    def _focus_in_event(self, widget, event):
        if self._default:
            self.set_text('')
            self.modify_text(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse('black'))

    def _focus_out_event(self, widget, event):
        if gtk.Entry.get_text(self) == '':
            self.set_text(self.placeholder)
            self.modify_text(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse('gray'))
            self._default = True
        else:
            self._default = False

    def get_text(self):
        if self._default:
            return ''
        return gtk.Entry.get_text(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = gtk.Window()
    vbox = gtk.VBox()
    w.add(vbox)
    vbox.pack_start(PlaceholderEntry())
    quitbtn = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_QUIT)
    quitbtn.connect('clicked', gtk.main_quit)
    vbox.pack_start(quitbtn)
    w.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
    w.show_all()
    gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

Since version 3.2, Gtk+ supports GtkEntry placeholder, but the only way to take advantage of it with Python is by using [PyGobject](http://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) instead of PyGtk.

Regards

Comment: Hi eagleoneraptor, welcome to stackoverflow, thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PyGobject instead of pygtk, and then setting a placeholder is a piece of cake:
    entry.set_placeholder_text("some string")